# Group by foreign key as boolean in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model in which I have a `ForeignKey` and an `IntegerField`.

I want to sum the integer field grouped by the foreign key but the foreign key can have many values. I am only interested in knowing if the foreign key has a 'real value' or is none. So the foreign key should be interpreted as a boolean.

I could make two queries:

```
a = Model.objects.filter(parent=None).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
b = Model.objects.exclude(parent=None).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

but isn't it less memory demanding to make something like

```
c = Model.objects.values('parent__as_bool').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your second option isn't valid because you need to filter the queryset before asking for values, and to specify what you're calling your annotation. As far as treating a foreignkey as a boolean is concerned you're looking for [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull). So you end with something like:

```
c = Model.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False).values().annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use .extra, like this:

```
.extra(select={'parent_is_null': "parent is NULL"})
```

see [docs for more examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)